# Harry Potter fanfiction about Sirius Black having a daughter with Lucius' sister

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

There's a story on Quotev about Sirius Black having a daughter. Her uncle is Lucius Malfoy, because her mother was Lucius' sister. I have been looking for it for about two weeks and can't find it.

I also forgot to say that she was raised by Remus Lupin instant of the Malfoys and that she didn't know Lucius Malfoy was her uncle until Draco told her. Her mother is dead. There two stories to it, I believe, but I can't remember.

Comment: Please tell me that one day Lucius gets angry at the sister and yells: "Are you f****** serious?!?" and she just nods.

Comment: When did you read it?

Comment: @Möoz I wish I could bounty this comment of yours

Comment: I can't really remember but she being raised by Remus Lupin because her mom is dead and don't know Lucius is her uncle

Comment: @Brittanybeach Do you remember where you read it? It would also help if you could go through the suggestions [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11922/82909) and see if you can add anything else.

Comment: @Laurel question seems to explicitely say Quotev, though aye linking the guide is always useful

Comment: @Jenayah Ooops yeah I missed that.

Comment: I have no idea who started the trope, but "Daughter of Sirius Black, dead mother, raised by Lupin, falls in love with a Weasley" is _incredibly_ common. I found at least seven of them, a couple of them have the girl being related to the Malfoys, but I don't really have much more time right now, so if anyone wants to dig deeper, be my guest. (continued)

Comment: (continued)  [1](https://www.quotev.com/story/11408413/Black-Robyn), [2](https://www.quotev.com/story/10033750/Until-the-End), [3](https://www.quotev.com/story/10393813/Electro-A-Fred-Weasley-Love-Story), [4](https://www.quotev.com/story/5358244/Crazy-Stupid-Love-George-Weasley-Love-Story), [5](https://www.quotev.com/story/3939649/Secrets-Fred-Weasley-Love-Story), [6](https://www.quotev.com/story/7079611/Alwaysfred-weasley/1), [7](https://www.quotev.com/story/8982406/Tag-Youre-It/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a bit terse, but the summary of [*The Blackened Desire*](https://www.quotev.com/story/10499526/The-Blackened-Desire) (published 10 months ago by author lilly) might be a fit:

> She was Slytherin’s top student, guaranteed to be Prefect and Head Girl. **She was Sirius Black’s daughter, the niece of Lucius and Narcissa Malfoy**, the older cousin of Draco Malfoy, and the lover of Hogwarts’ Redheaded prankster, George Weasley. Life for her sounded perfect, didn’t it? But things weren’t always that way. The story starts with Evelyn Black, as an uptight, higher class, blood supremacist girl and George Weasley, the wild prankster, who didn’t have a care in the world. The two combination seemed quite odd, but still… even after all those times… she still remained his Blackened Desire.

You said that her mother "was" Lucius' sister, so I'm guessing she's dead. In this story, Lucius' sister was murdered - officially, by Sirius Black, but the actual reason is something Evelyn is investigating:

> "Alex, I've been thinking. What if Mum was poisoned to death?" I saw him roll his eyes at my theory and immediately pointed to the paper, where I had written down all of the evidence. The library at Malfoy Manor was the only place where we could actually talk without getting eavesdropped on. I'm going to be truthful here, without Alex, this library would be deserted.
>
> "No, I'm serious, hear me out. The Aurors found a teacup next to her lifeless body, and despite everything in the house being demolished, the teacup was still intact. What if it was charmed somehow--"
>
> [...]
>
> **"Evelyn, you know for a fact Uncle Lucius wouldn't be happy if he knew you were investigating this again,"** I sighed, slumping a little bit, before straightening up again.  **My mum was murdered when I was two years old**. When, why, and how, still remains a mystery to this day.
>
> Well, to me and my brother, Alex, of course. **The ministry, however, thinks my dad, Sirius Black, was responsible for her death and the death of twelve muggles**. So, as a result, he's been in Azkaban ever since I could remember.

---

Eventually found with the Google query `lucius niece "daughter of" sirius black uncle site:quotev.com`

Comment: Hi @Brittanybeach, may I suggest you edit these new details in the question?  Also, I see you've accepted my answer - that's nice of you, but as this is not the one you were looking for, it would be better to unaccept it until someone finds the right one :)

Answer (score 0):

There’s blinded by lies. Technically hermione was sirius’ niece but he blood adopted her after both her parents died.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You can improve your answer by including a link to the fic in question, and also be explaining in more detail how it matches the question.