# Harry Potter fanfiction where the main character is Sirius's daughter, but doesn't know who her father is

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a Harry Potter fanfiction I read a little while ago.

In it, the main character is Sirius's daughter, but doesn't know who her father is and her mother is dead, so she lives with the Malfoys. I'm pretty sure she is French or went to Beauxbatons before, but goes to Hogwarts now and went last year.

Also the story starts off with her bumping into Lupin at the train station and she sees Sirius as a dog, but doesn't know that it's her father. Also she is wearing Muggle clothes at the time, like a maroon skirt or something. Sorry this is so random, lol, but please help me find it!

Comment: I just typed "harry potter fanfiction sirius daughter" in google and got tons of results. It looks like a lot of fanfictions involve a daughter of sirius black. For instance, all fanfictions on that page involve a daughter or son of Sirius: https://www.fanfiction.net/community/Papa-Padfoot/101422/

Comment: Do you by any chance remember her first name? It would help a lot. Emily Black, Cassiopeia Black, Cordelia Black, Elizabeth Black...?

Comment: Artemis Phoenix Black? This one goes to Beauxbatons and I found several mentions of the muggle dresses: https://www.fanfiction.net/s/6376563/1/Rise-of-the-Phoenix

Comment: All these fanfictions also involve a daughter or son of Sirius: https://archiveofourown.org/tags/Parent%20Sirius%20Black/works

Comment: Possibly related question: [Harry Potter fanfiction about Sirius Black having a daughter with Lucius's sister?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/197943/harry-potter-fanfiction-about-sirius-black-having-a-daughter-with-luciuss-siste?rq=1)

Comment: Henrika Black lives with her mother Beatrice Malfoy: https://www.wattpad.com/story/328828074-henrika-black-sirius-black%27s-daughther